# How to get product attribute link on WooCommerce single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I am using WooCommerce and I want to get the current product attribute URL to be used on the single product page, replacing the code `<category_url>/?filter_preco=` by the URL.

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'cj_show_attribute_links', 4 );

function cj_show_attribute_links() {
    global $post, $product;
    $attribute_names = array( 'pa_preco' ); // Insert attribute names here

    foreach ( $attribute_names as $attribute_name ) {
        $taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $attribute_name );

        if ( $taxonomy && ! is_wp_error( $taxonomy ) ) {
            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $attribute_name );
            $terms_array = array();

            if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                   $archive_link =  $term->slug;
                   $base = '<category_url>?filter_preco=';
                   $full_line = '<h4 style="font-size: 15px; color: #4E4E4E;"><a href="'. $base .'' . $archive_link . '">'. $term->name . '</a></h4><div class="is-divider small"></div>';
                   array_push( $terms_array, $full_line );
                }

                echo ' ' . implode( $terms_array);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by using this (I am getting a error when the product has no category)

```
function pagina_produto_embaixo_titulo() {
global $post;
$attribute_names = array( 'pa_preco' ); // Insert attribute names here

foreach ( $attribute_names as $attribute_name ) {
    $taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $attribute_name );
    

    if ( $taxonomy && ! is_wp_error( $taxonomy ) ) {
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $attribute_name );
        $terms_array = array();
        
        

        if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
               $archive_link =  $term->slug;
               $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
               $link = get_term_link( $terms[0]->term_id, 'product_cat' );
               $base = $link .'?filter_preco=';
               //erro nas 2 linhas acima, quando o produto nao tem categoria, e na pagina da loja, deixa de funcuonar algus coisas.
               $full_line = '<h4 style="font-size: 15px; color: #4E4E4E;"><a href="https://www.cotacaodebrindes.com.br/o-que-e-ustar/" target="_blank">O que é µStar+?</a> | <a href="'. $base .'' . $archive_link . '">'. $term->name . '</a></h4><div>';
               array_push( $terms_array, $full_line );
            }

            echo ' ' . implode( $terms_array);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

There are some mistakes in your code… Use this replacement code that uses `get_term_link()` WordPress function to get the term link as follows:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_linked_product_attributes', 4 );
function display_linked_product_attributes() {
    global $post, $product;

    $taxonomy = array( 'pa_preco' ); // Here define product attribute(s) taxonomy(ies)

    foreach ( $attribute_names as $attribute_name ) {
        $terms  = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy );
        $output = '';
        
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
           $link    = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );
           $output .= '<h4 style="font-size: 15px; color: #4E4E4E;"><a href="'. $link . '">'. $term->name . '</a></h4><div class="is-divider small"></div>';
        }
        echo ' ' . $output;
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should better work.

Comment: Hi, the code is goind in functions.php  of the childtheme (flatsome theme)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the result is null, the code have no result on product page ... no error, no results

Comment: @ReginaldoHiga Is "Preco" set as a product attribute, so it's taxonomy is "pa_preco"? can you make a screen shot of  "Preco" attribute backend setting and add it in your question? If it's a custom attribute (not a taxonomy attribute), you can't get terms from it (and not a term link)…

Comment: This is a custom woocommerce attribute that I have added PRODUCT >attribute, just like The Color, the Size

Comment: @ReginaldoHiga Understand that "custom attributes" only exist in the product where they have been added and don't have any available link for their values… Only product attributes set in "Products" > "Attributes" section are a custom taxonomy with terms that have available links.